# Jquery replacement for toggle not working

Tags: jquery, toggle

I made a function that replaces the .toggle() so I can add more stuff into it, but it doesn't work.
When I click on the h1 element it does turn into class="off" but it won't turn back to class="on" if I click on it again.

```
<body>
    <h1 class="on">Show second word!</h1>
    <h2 id="submenu">hello</h2>


    <script>
    $("#submenu").hide();

    $('.on').click(function()
    {
        $(this).removeClass('on');
        $(this).addClass('off');
        $('#submenu').show();
    });


    $('.off').click(function()
    {
        $(this).removeClass('on');
        $(this).addClass('off');
        $('#submenu').hide();
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Jfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/T6MgH/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of errors and you should take advantage of event delegation:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.on', function()
    {
        $(this).removeClass('on');
        $(this).addClass('off');
        $('#submenu').show();
    });


    $(document).on('click', '.off', function()
    {
        $(this).removeClass('off');  // these were out of order in your fiddle
        $(this).addClass('on'); // so they are now flipped
        $('#submenu').hide();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/T6MgH/3/

Comment: Hi thank you for reply, may I ask what event delegation means? Sorry I'm stil learning.

Comment: You use event delegation to handle items that appear in the DOM later - such as your adding the `.off` class suddenly. The jQuery has already executed at that point and isn't aware of the new items being added. New items still have events that happen, and those events bubble up the DOM reaching other elements that were there when the jQuery code ran. By delegating the new items events to old elements jQuery can still capture the event and act on it. Does that make sense? I delegated to 'document' in my example, because I know it was there when jQuery ran.

Answer (score 1):

Your events are not reactive, so changing class will not change the function it trigger. Once you page load, jQuery apply event on every `.on` and an event on every `.off`.

You could use event delegation to solve that but why not simply use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)?

```
$('.on').click(function()
{
    $(this).toggleClass('on off'); //Can be removed if there is no style associated.
    $('#submenu').toggle();
});
```

---

## Edit

An other solution is to use an active class and check for the class

```
$('.on').click(function()
{
    $(this).toggleClass('off')
    if($(this).hasClass('off')){
        //Close function
        $(this).hide();
    }else{
        //Open function
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice! I should have pointed out that only the `.toggle()` event handler was the one being deprecated, not the effect.

Comment: Hi thank you for reply, it's because I want some things to fadeIn and fadeOut and I don't think it's possible with toggle.

Comment: Yep and you can also use the callback in the toggle function to add more functionality of you desire.

Comment: @user3406286 Added an other solution. So my answer combine with Jay's answer give you all possibility.

Answer (score -1):

The .off class is not present in the dom initially. The click event is not attached with it. So that function is will not work. So you need to bind event on the .off class when it's added.

```
$(document).on('click', '.on', function()
{
    $(this).removeClass('on');
    $(this).addClass('off');
    $('#submenu').show();
});


$(document).on('click', '.off', function()
{
    $(this).removeClass('off');  // these were out of order in your fiddle
    $(this).addClass('on'); // so they are now flipped
    $('#submenu').hide();
});
});
```

It'll work, because here @Jay Blanchard added the event on the document, not on a specific item. And the document is always present.

Or, there is very simple way, if you just what to show & hide the #submenu, don't change the on/off class. Use the following.

```
  $('.on').click(function()
        {
            if($('#submenu').hasClass('show')){
                $('#submenu').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
                $('#submenu').hide();
            } else {
                $('#submenu').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
                $('#submenu').show();

            }

        });
```

If  your are using define css for show & hide class as display : block; & dispaly : none; the you don't even have to use the $('#submenu').show(); & $('#submenu').hide(); function.

Comment: You literally copied [@JayBlanchard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24192836/2324107) answer code and even left his comments in the code...

Comment: Whoa - I've been *plagiarized*.

Comment: @Indra Hi, it appears that you copied this answer from http://stackoverflow.com/a/24192836/1011527. You're using someone else's work without giving the author credit. This amounts to plagiarism, and is not welcome on Stack Overflow. Remember to always add prominent attribution when using other sources. I have edited your post to indicate where you got the first code block from. Thanks!